# Turning $\frac{(x^2+y^2-a_p^2)^2}{4b_p^2(x+a_p)^2}+\frac{4(x+a_p)^2y^2}{((x+a_p)^2+y^2)^2}=1$ into $(x^2+y^2)^2=ax^3+(a-b)xy^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to simplify the following equation ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnH0f.png)):
$$
\frac{(x^2+y^2-a_p^2)^2}{4b_p^2(x+a_p)^2} + \frac{4(x+a_p)^2y^2}{((x+a_p)^2+y^2)^2} = 1
$$

By substituting $a=2(a_p+b_p),b=4b_p$ to get
$$(x^2+y^2)^2=ax^3+(a-b)xy^2$$
I have been trying for HOURS now, but it's just too complicated for me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you trying to simplify it? e.g. get y as a function of x?

Comment: Do you mean substitution $a=2(a_p+b_p)$ and $b=4b_p$ ? Note use underscore $\_$ to denote subscripts.  Also please check the result you want. If $y=0$, the original equation gives $x=a_p\pm 2b_p$, while your last equation gives something else.

Comment: Unsure if this approach will solve the problem.  The approach **might fail**.  The premise is of form $$\frac{E^2}{F^2} + \frac{G^2}{H^2} = 1,$$ which resembles an equation of the form $\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$.  So, my attempt would be to identify the complete set of satisfying ordered pairs $(x,y)$ in terms of $a_p, b_p$, such that for each such ordered pair $(x,y)$ an angle $\theta$ can be found, so that the corresponding terms represent $\sin^2(\theta)$ and $\cos^2(\theta)$.  Again, I emphasize, this entire approach **might fail**.

Comment: [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/klw9qmdj7s) is an interactive Desmos graph.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales And a very pretty graph it is

Comment: I second Golden_Ratio's question: what are you seeking to get? The implicit function theorem might help you *approximate* it, but judging by the graph from John, a closed form exact solution for $y$ in terms of $x$, or visa versa, will most likely be impossible

Comment: @FShrike Personally, I would have $\theta$ range through the interval $(-\pi, \pi]$, and seek to specify $x,y$ in terms of $a_p, b_p, \cos(\theta),$ and $\sin(\theta)$.  If such an approach works, this would create a relationship between $x$ and $y$, based on $a_p, b_p,$ and $\theta$.  Therefore, each value of $\theta$ would create its own subset of satisfying values $(x,y)$.